# React-Native Navigation Experimental(NavigationStateUtils), purpose of using a slice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook, navigation, react-native

React-Native Navigation Experimental on NavigationStateUtils.js,

What is the purpose of Using a Slice over here, as it returns same exact array of routes even though slice() is not used.

[image]

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9ee815f6b52e0c2417c04e5a05e1e31df26daed2/Libraries/NavigationExperimental/NavigationStateUtils.js#L66

Or it is Just there to be consistent with pop.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose is probably to create a copy of the `state.routes` array before modifying it, so as not to mutate the original array referenced by `state.routes`.  Keeping your data structures immutable (by making a copy that you modify, rather than modifying the original) can help to avoid unexpected bugs when an array/object/etc. is modified by some other part of the code.  It's a commonly used principle in Functional programming, a paradigm which React generally adheres to.

Comment: Thanks for the detail Explanation @lt1. I understand the immutability part but how does  const routes = state.routes.slice(); is different from  const routes = state.routes ?

Comment: the new array is a shallow copy

Comment: If we do `const routes = state.routes`, it isn't obvious, but we aren't creating a copy of the `state.routes` array- you are just creating a new variable `routes` that is actually still referencing the same underlying array in memory as `state.routes`.  For more explanation of that, you could look up the concepts of `pass by value` vs. `pass by reference`.   You have to use something like `.slice()` to actually create a copy of the underlying array, before assigning that to a new variable.

Comment: Awesome . ! Now I get it.